# Deploying a single Windows image to multiple pieces of hardware?

Tags: windows, windows-10, deployment, adk

I have two NUCs that I would like the same image to be used on. [NUC5PGYHR](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-nuc5pgyh.html) and the [NUC DC3217IYE](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-dc3217iye-board-d33217gke.html). I'm using a base Windows 10 LTSB image on both of them now.

High level of the hardware differences:

1. eMMC vs mSATA
2. Pentium vs i3
3. 2GB vs 4GB

I'd like to have the image support both of them so I can just deploy to either with DISM when a set up is needed.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Windows 10 Ultimate`.  It should be as simple, as using DISM to apply the .wim image, to a given partitions.  You can automate this function using a script if you want.

Comment: @Ramhound I have attempted that. Blue screens on both NUCs. I'm just trying to avoid installing drivers at runtime.

Comment: Did you sysprep the reference system before creating the image?